# Finding text in a "textbox"

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm writing an Excel VBA snippet which looks for a string of text in a docx. It works for regular text, but doesn't find the string if it's in a "textbox" within the docx (although a manual search within MS Word verifies it's there).

```
Dim tempDoc As Word.Document
Set tempDoc = Documents.Open(fileName:=foundName, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, Visible:=False)
Dim fromDate As Word.Range
Set fromDate = tempDoc.Range 
Dim fromCopyRange As Word.Range
                      
fromDate.Find.Execute FindText:="covers period", MatchCase:=False

If fromDate.Find.Found = True Then 'this normally works, except if the text is in a textbox
                
     Set fromCopyRange = tempDoc.Range(Start:=fromDate.End + 1, End:=fromDate.End + 20)
     foundResult = Trim(fromCopyRange.Text)
     Debug.Print foundResult

End If
```

Comment: You simple use the wrong function. Like you can see, it searches in `tempDoc.Range`. If yo need to search a string from a text box, you should iterate between the text boxes in their collection and extract if from the one where it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add something like this to your code.

```
Dim shp As Word.Shape
For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
    If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
        If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
            'do something
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I've seen that code before! Probably doesn't need ', iShp As Word.InlineShape', though.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to delete it ... edited it now though.